# People attack innocent questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Example:
[how does url shortner work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572734/how-does-url-shortner-work)

I know it's kind of stupid question compared to great questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/left-padding-integers-with-zeros-in-java), but I think it's good that somebody wants to learn something and since be definition Stackoverflow wants to replace Google (so you don't have to waste time going to Google), this question should be allowed. Why does it have 3 close votes already?

Comment: Question was greedy and mangled 13 other questions into the one. Why leave a ramble open?

Comment: From the question: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, **overly broad**, or rhetorical and **cannot be reasonably answered in its current form**.

Comment: I am avid closer and downvoter, but I feel the OP has a point here. The question was asked in good faith, and found an okay answer.

Comment: This is self-inflicted.  SO doesn't demand participation, but it is quite visible.  And if you've got only a 44% accept rate and *never* voted for anything then you'd better ask a good question to be taken seriously.  People trump rules, `We don't run Stack Overflow. You do`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact that Wikipedia could answer it means very little research was done beforehand.  Also, there's about 10 questions crammed into there...  I, for one, wouldn't know where to start.  The SO users are not the personal Google-monkeys of whoever comes along.  Questions of this type are very hard to answer(not that the answer is difficult) which makes them bad questions, and it's, IMHO, very inconsiderate of the OP.

Comment: I Stated this a while back and i was flamed by moderators for saying that people SO Is a wiki in itself so why send users to another site.

Comment: I'd hope SO is more authoritative than Wikipedia, which has some quality control issues. I'm not claiming SO doesn't, of course.

Comment: @Phil: Oh, trust me, when needed, Jeff can be **very** authoritative.